# How to pass a Json array to JPQL Where clause for IN operator?

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I've a multiple drop down select box available to select the list of genres. I'm creating a JSON array in JavaScript with all the genres selected by user & passing them to the back end Java function for plotting graph.

```
Database : MySQL
```

JavaScript:

```
var items = {};

    $(function() {
        $('#genres1').change(function() {
            console.log($(this).val());
            items.genres = $(this).val();
        }).multipleSelect({
            width: '56%'
        });
    });

    var genres = items.genres.map(function(e){
              return JSON.stringify(e);
            });
        var selectedGenres = genres.join(", ");
        alert(selectedGenres); // Outputs : "Action", "Horror" and so on.... based on selection
```

Java:

```
public static void myFun(String genre){
            Logger.info("Genre"+genre); //prints "Action","Horror"
            List<String> selectedGenres = Arrays.asList(genre);
            //List<String> selectedGenres = Arrays.asList("Action","Horror"); //Correct output
            Logger.info("Genre"+selectedGenres); //prints ["Action","Horror"]
            String queryString="SELECT wD FROM sed WHERE genre IN (:genres)";
            Query query1=JPA.em().createNativeQuery(queryString).setParameter("genres", selectedGenres);
}
```

I'm not knowing how the array has to be passed to the query.

```
//List<String> selectedGenres = Arrays.asList("Action","Horror"); //Correct output
```

This hardcoded value gives me the correct output. When I pass the **"selectedGenres"** array containing exactly the same as above input - `"Action","Horror"`I don't get the preferred output. I also tried to send "genre" as it is as a parameter but it did not work though. I'm getting empty response. Can someone correct me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> selectedGenres = Arrays.asList(genre);
```

Some API clarification: `Arrays#asList` accepts `String...` vargs, where every argument is an element value to create the actual List.

Back to your method: your input argument is `String genre` (**a String**) while `#asList` method is not aware that this `genre` string is actually an array (and should not), and it does its job correctly - upon receiving a single element (a `String` in our case), a single-dimensional `List` is created.

To solve the issue, you may want to try one of those options:

1. (if your string is JSON array) Use JSON parsing library (such as [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core))
2. Try to split the input (`genre`) by a comma, and transform that array back to List.

Comment: I'll try this. Thanks for the input @Michael Arenzon